# Play video from an Url without webview

Tags: android

I have to play Dailymotion videos in an Android APP, but I must not do it in a WebView . VideoView class just accepts files streamed, and Dailymotion API has'nt got any resource for Android.

Does anyone know how to implement it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
String LINK = "Your_Link_Goes_Here";
setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

Try out this code..

Answer (score 0):

VideoView is the best and in video view you can play streaming url also you can play the local files which you have on device sdcard or embeeded with in your app..

Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html) this a sample

[LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)